# Beginner attempt at a text adventure v2

Tags: python, beginner, adventure-game, battle-simulation

Based upon feedback received in [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/138607/my-beginner-attempt-at-a-text-adventure) post I've amended my game and would very much appreciate further feedback on it's current state(work in progress) and any suggestions on what I could implement in the future.

An @classmethod was introduced in Enemy() and these are completely new to me so a confirmation that all is correct with that would be very nice.

Code:

```
# A Countryside Adventure

#from adventureqmodule import *
from sys import exit
import random

def question(question, boolean = False, options = ["yes", "no"]):
    """
    If boolean, returns True or False. Otherwise returns a string
    regardless of type in options
    """
    options = ["yes", "no"] if boolean else [str(option) for option in options]
    while True:
        print(question)
        print("Options: {}".format(", ".join(options)))
        response = input("Input: ").lower()
        if boolean and response in ["y", "n"] + options:
            return response[0] == "y"
        if response in options:
            return response
        else:
            print("That isn't a valid response.")

class Character(object):
    """A character in a fictional world"""

    def __init__(self, name, health):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.dead = False

    def __str__(self):
        rep = self.name + " has health: " + str(self.health)
        return rep

    def attack(self, other):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def take_damage(self, damage):
        self.health -= damage



class Player(Character):
    """A player in a fictional world"""

    def __init__(self, name, health = 10):
        super(Player, self).__init__(name, health)
        self.inventory = ["axe handle", "first aid kit"]
        self.inventory_max = 2
        self.strikes = {"headbutt" : 4 , "kick" : 3, "punch"\
                        : random.randrange(1, 4)}

    def __str__(self):
        rep = super(Player, self).__str__()
        rep += "\nInventory: " + str(self.inventory)
        return rep


    def find_items(self, location_items):
        print("On the ground you see: {}".format(", ".join(location_items)))
        print("Your inventory (max {} items) is: {}".format\
              (self.inventory_max, self.inventory))
        pick_up = True
        while pick_up:
            pick_up = question("Pick anything up?", boolean = True)
            if not pick_up:
                break
            item = input("What? ")

            if item in location_items:
                self.add_inventory(item, location_items)
            else:
                print("There is no such item here.")


    def add_inventory(self, item, location_items):
        if len(self.inventory) < self.inventory_max:
            self.inventory.append(item)
            location_items.remove(item)
            print("You picked up: {}".format(item))
            print("Your inventory is now: {}".format(self.inventory))

        elif len(self.inventory) == self.inventory_max:
            remove = question("Inventory full. Remove an item?", boolean = True)
            if remove:
                self.remove_inventory(location_items)
                location_items.remove(item)
                self.inventory.append(item)
            print("You picked up: {}".format(item))
            print("Your inventory is now: {}".format(self.inventory))


    def remove_inventory(self, location_items):
        remove_item = None
        while remove_item not in self.inventory:
            print("You inventory is: {}".format(self.inventory))
            remove_item = input("Which item do you want to remove? ")
            if remove_item not in self.inventory:
                print("Sorry, that isn't in your inventory.")
        location_items.append(remove_item)
        self.inventory.remove(remove_item)


    def attack(self, other):
        strike = question("\nStrike the {}?".format(other.name), boolean = True)
        if strike:
            strike_type = input("What type of strike(headbutt, kick, punch)? ")\
                          .lower()
            if strike_type in self.strikes:
                print("You got the {} with a {} and dealt {} damage!".format(\
                    other.name, strike_type, self.strikes.get(strike_type)))
                other.take_damage(self.strikes.get(strike_type))
            else:
                print("Oops. You missed!")
        else:
            print("You wuss!")



class Enemy(Character):
    """An enemy is a fictional world"""

    def __init__(self, name, health = 7, damage = 2):
        super(Enemy, self).__init__(name, health)
        self.damage = damage

    def attack(self, other):
        other.take_damage(self.damage)
        print("\nThe {} attacks and deals you {} damage!".format(self.name,\
                                                           self.damage))
    @classmethod
    def generate(cls):
        names = ["Boar", "Troll", "Wild cat"]
        enemy = Enemy(random.choice(names))
        return enemy

    def die(self):
        print("You have defeated the {}!".format(self.name))



class Location(object):
    """A location in an adventure game"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enemy = Enemy.generate()

    def enter(self):
        NotImplementedError

    def battle(self, player, enemy):
        """Player and an enemy battle"""
        print("A {} suddenly appears!".format(enemy.name))
        fight = question("\nFight or run?", options = ["fight", "run"])
        if fight == "fight":
            while player.health and enemy.health > 0:
                #print("\n")
                enemy.attack(player)
                if player.health <= 0:
                    break
                print(player)
                print(enemy)
                player.attack(enemy)

            if enemy.health <= 0:
                print("You have defeated the {}!".format(enemy.name))
                enemy.dead = True
                #enemy.die()
            elif player.health <= 0:
                print("You are killed by the {}!".format(enemy.name))
                player.dead = True

        else:
            print("You escaped unharmed. But he shall be waiting should you \
venture")
            print("to these parts again!")



class Meadow(Location):
    """A meadow in an adventure game"""

    def __init__(self): 
        super(Meadow, self).__init__()
        self.location_items = ["bottled water"] 

    def enter(self, player):
        #enemy  = self.generate_enemy()
        print(player)
        print("\nYou are in a meadow.")
        if self.location_items:
            player.find_items(self.location_items)
        if not self.enemy.dead:
            self.battle(player, self.enemy)
            if player.dead:
                return "dead"
        else:
            print("The slain body of the {} lies slumped pathetically on the\
 ground.".format(self.enemy.name))

        print("\nTo your left is a beach, to your right a forest.")
        left_right = question("Which way do you go? ", options = ["left",\
                                                                  "right"])

        if left_right == "left":
            return "beach"
        else:
            return "forest"


class Beach(Location):
    """A beach location in an adventure game"""

    def __init__(self): 
        super(Beach, self).__init__()
        self.location_items = ["chocolate bar"] 

    def enter(self, player):
        print(player)
        print("\nYou are at the beach.")
        if self.location_items:
            player.find_items(self.location_items)
        print("location items after adjustment: {}".format(self.location_items))
        if not self.enemy.dead:
            self.battle(player, self.enemy)
            if player.dead:
                return "dead"
        else:
            print("You pass the lifeless body of the {}.".format(self.enemy.\
                                                                 name))
        print("\nTo your left is a meadow, to your right a forest.")
        left_right = question("Which way do you go? ", options = ["left",\
                                                                  "right"])

        if left_right == "left":
            return "meadow"
        else:
            return "forest"


class Forest(Location):
    """A forest in an adventure game"""

    def __init__(self): 
        super(Forest, self).__init__()
        self.location_items = ["crossbow"] 

    def enter(self, player):
        print(player)
        print("\nYou are in the forest.")
        if self.location_items:
            player.find_items(self.location_items)
        print("location items after adjustment: {}".format(self.location_items))
        if not self.enemy.dead:
            self.battle(player, self.enemy)
            if player.dead:
                return "death"
        else:
            print("You smile as you pass the corpse of the {}.".format(\
                self.enemy.name))

        print("\nTo your left is meadow, to your right a beach.")
        left_right = question("Which way do you go?", options = ["left",\
                                                                 "right"])
        if left_right == "left":
            return "meadow"
        else:
            return "beach"



class Game(object):
    """A fictional countryside adventure"""

    def __init__(self, location_map):
        self.location_map = location_map

    def play(self):
        current_location = self.location_map.start_location()
        while True:
            next_location_name = current_location.enter(self.\
                                                        location_map.player)
            if next_location_name == "dead":
                print("Game Over")
                break
            current_location = self.location_map.next_location\
                               (next_location_name)


class Map(object):

    LOCATIONS = {"meadow" : Meadow(),
                 "beach" : Beach(),
                 "forest" : Forest()}

    def __init__(self, location, player):
        self.location = location
        self.player = player

    def next_location(self, location_name):
        return self.LOCATIONS.get(location_name)

    def start_location(self):
        return self.next_location(self.location)


def main():
    print("\n\n\t\tCountryside adventure")
    name = input("\n\nWelcome adventurer! What might be your name? ").title()
    print("\nI wish you the very best of luck, {}!.\n".format(name))

    player = Player(name)
    a_map = Map("meadow", player)
    game = Game(a_map)
    game.play()

play = True
while play:
    main()
    play = question("Do you want to play again?", boolean = True)
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use another nice python decorator, `@property` to make the check for dead easier:

```
class Character(object):
    ...
    @property
    def dead(self):
        return self.health <= 0
...
class Location(object):
    ...
    def battle(self, player, enemy):
        ...
        attacker, defender = enemy, player
        while True:
            attacker.attack(defender)
            if defender.dead:
                break
            print(defender)
            attacker, defender = defender, attacker
        action = "are killed by" if player.dead else "have defeated"
        print("You {} the {.name}!".format(action, enemy))
```

This means you can access `player.dead` like an attribute and on every access he will actually call `player.dead()` to check the health of the player. I also swapped around the checks, because if the player is dead it does not matter whether the enemy is also dead!

**EDIT:** I now transformed the while loop into an infinite loop of an `attacker` attacking a `defender` where the two roles are swapped around, starting with `enemy` attacking `player`. I also made the printing more generic, the two strings were quite similar.

Comment: Thanks! Very cool. I want get this type of efficiency into my code.

Comment: Are there any benefits to making dead a property and not just using a function call to player.dead()? The only difference I see at the moment is that you can omit the ().

Comment: I think that the primary benefit is that you don't have to have the `character.health <= 0` check in multiple places in the codebase - the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle.

Comment: What @silleknarf said. Also if you ever want to change the check for deadness, it is now in one place. Maybe a magical item keeps your soul in this plane even if your health is below zero? Just add a check for that in dead, instead of everywhere where you now check the health.